# ¿Cómo agregar varios jButton en una celda de un jTable?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, jtable

Quisiera saber como agregar algunos **`jButton`** en una celda de un **`jTable`** para realizar acciones como **eliminar** o **modificar**.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas mostrar un botón en una columna, entonces necesitas crear un renderizador y un editor personalizados para la columna. Lee la sección del tutorial de [Swing - Conceptos: Editores y renderizadores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) para obtener información básica.

A continuación, echa un vistazo a la [columna del botón de la tabla](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) para un enfoque.

Comment: Si lo estaba haciendo así, pero quería saber si hay la posibilidad de poner 2 botones en una misma celda

Comment: En principio puedes poner cualquier tipo de componente, un componente puede ser un JPanel lo cual te permitiría colocar dos botones. Sería bueno ver algún avance para ayudarte a completarlo.